# can i share React user post length to other component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-state

I have a component for post page , it's have ,
**const [posts , setPosts] = useState([]);**
which value is 11 posts can see by **console.log(posts)** , what is want is i want to show post length in another component , which have user information , a user card with all posts , followers etc . i am new and using Redux-toolkit

Comment: Why is the `posts` array stored in the posts page and not in the redux store?

Answer (score 1):

```
function YourComponentPostPage(props){
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]) //this is an empty array when first render
   return (
     <AnotherComponentWithUserInfo posts = {posts} />
   )
}
function AnotherComponentWithUserInfo(props){
  render(
      <View><Text>{props.posts}</Text></View>
  )
}
```

If your parent component has a value and you want to pass it down to a children component, the syntax is the code above.
In the parent component has to catch the value from a Redux store, you need to use {connect} function from react-redux pack, but i don't think is the case you're asking about

Here a good link where to start: https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react

Here the link for the docs regarding Props: https://reactnative.dev/docs/props